# Visual studio xamarin emulator for android not showing

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I am new to mobile development. So i am using xamarin for this purpose. I have following this [sample code](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/hello-xamarin-forms/quickstart/) as a starter in mobile development.

I am using visual studio 15 for it. I have followed all the steps mentioned in sample code. For now i want it to run only on android, so i have chosen `.Droid` as my `Startup` project, but on `Debug Target` i cannot find `Xamarin Emulator for android` all i find is the android emulators list. Please see the image bellow

[image]

While on clicking the `Manage Virual Devices` i get the following list of devices as shown in bellow image

[image]

I have searched many articles on it but couldn't find any solution

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xamarin Emulator for android isn't a specific emulator.
The android emulator's list is a list of devices for you to emulate; the virtual devices page is a list of devices/OS versions emulators that can be downloaded.

Select/Download an emulator profile in the device/size/OS version that fits your needs and run your code.

Comment: Yes but it's not running and i am getting lots of errors to update packages, and when i update package i again get an error that 'this package cannot be installed'

Comment: If you want to update this question or possibly ask a new one I can try and help; no guarantees I'll have an answer of course. There are a lot of existing Q/A regarding package problems; hopefully one of those covers what you need though.